# Square with a cross in it as a figure caption using tikz in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, captions

[image: I am trying to reproduce this caption in Latex using tikz]

I have defined these shapes like this:

```
\newcommand{\markerone}{\raisebox{0.9pt}{\tikz{\node[draw,scale=0.4,regular polygon,, regular polygon sides=4,fill=black!20!black](){};}}}
```

and

```
\caption{Isomerization rate constant (per open Sn, 373 K) and Sn content for samples grafted in isopropanol reflux (\protect\markerseven), in dichloromethane reflux starting from Al-Beta-OH-54 (\protect\markersix), Al-Beta-F-45 ( ), Al-Beta-OH-29 (\protect\markereight), Al-Beta-OH-22 ( ), Al-Beta-OH-19 (\protect\markerfour), and hydrothermally-synthesized Sn-Beta-F (\protect\markertwo) [26]. Dashed lines represent the average rate constant (per open Sn, 373 K) for Sn-Beta-F samples prepared hydrothermally and Sn-Beta-OH samples.}
```

Is there an easy way to add the cross and + inside a square using similar code and Tikz? I couldn't find another answer that applied to the specific case of figure captions

Comment: Why not just use `\boxtimes` and `\boxplus` of the `amsmath` package?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think there is a real need for `tikz` in this case. The following and many others are available from `amssymb`, see [Math symbols defined by LaTeX package `amssymb`](http://milde.users.sourceforge.net/LUCR/Math/mathpackages/amssymb-symbols.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}     
\begin{document}

Some text $(\boxplus)$ and some other text ...

Some text $(\boxtimes)$ and some other text ...

\end{document}​
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize amsyymb was out there

Answer (score 3):

Why reinvent the wheel?

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{amssymb}


\begin{document}
Blablabla $\boxtimes$ yadayada.
\end{document}
```

Comment: And they are coming down the stretch, neck and neck, and AboAmmar wins by a nose (less than a minute)!

Comment: +1 anyway, as this happened to me so many times when I used to answer regularly:)